# Tensorflow Layers API CNN parameters wont change during training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow so the problem might be really silly.

I have been trying to write a simple CNN for a MNIST handwritten digits dataset using Tensorflow. The problem is that parameters are not updated by the Optimizer(being monitored by Tensorboard summary).
Graph seems OK, even though scopes created by Layers API seem weird. Gradients are computed from every layer.
Please, help!

I am using training data from here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

DATA = 'train-images.idx3-ubyte'
LABELS = 'train-labels.idx1-ubyte'
NUM_EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 15
#Data definition
data_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([DATA,])
label_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([LABELS,])

reader_data = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=28*28, header_bytes = 16)
reader_labels = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=1, header_bytes = 8)

(_,data_rec) = reader_data.read(data_queue)
(_,label_rec) = reader_labels.read(label_queue)

image = tf.decode_raw(data_rec, tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])
label = tf.decode_raw(label_rec, tf.uint8)
label = tf.reshape(label, [1])

image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label],
                                                 batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                 capacity=100,
                                                 min_after_dequeue = 30)
#Layers definition
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
  inputs=tf.cast(image_batch, tf.float32),
  filters=15,
  kernel_size=[5,5],
  padding='same',
  activation=tf.nn.relu)

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
  inputs=conv,
  filters=15,
  kernel_size=[3,3],
  padding='same',
  activation=tf.nn.relu)

pool_flat = tf.reshape(conv1, [BATCH_SIZE, -1])

dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool_flat, units=30, activation=tf.nn.relu)

output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=10))

#train operation definition
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(tf.reshape(label_batch,[-1]), tf.int32), depth=10)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels,
                                       logits=output)

global_step = tf.Variable(0,name='global_step',trainable=False)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss, global_step = global_step)

#Summaries definition

for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='conv2d'):
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='conv2d_1'):
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='dense'):
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='dense_1'):
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
tf.summary.image("inp", image_batch, max_outputs =1)
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()

#init
sess = tf.Session()
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log_simple_stats', sess.graph)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#loop
for i in range((60000*NUM_EPOCHS)//BATCH_SIZE):
    sess.run(train_op)
    if(i%100):
        merged = sess.run(summaries)
        summary_writer.add_summary(merged, i)


coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

EDIT
Custom layers give same result.

Custom layers definitions:

```
def convol(input, inp, outp, name="conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, inp, outp], stddev=0.1),name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[outp]), name="B")
        filtered = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME", name="conv2d")
        activation = tf.nn.relu(features=(filtered+b), name="activation")
        tf.summary.histogram(name=w.name, values=w)
        tf.summary.histogram(name=b.name, values=b)
        tf.summary.histogram(name=activation.name, values=activation)
        return activation

def dense(input, inp, outp, name="dense"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([inp, outp], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[outp]), name="B")
        act = tf.matmul(input, w) + b
        tf.summary.histogram(name=w.name, values=w)
        tf.summary.histogram(name=b.name, values=b)
        tf.summary.histogram(name="activation", values=act)
        return act
```

EDIT:

So after some time messing with this and MNIST examples from tf I have noticed that weights  are not being learned. The way I have handled the data reading has messed up something about gradient computation. I have just taped the class that reads MNIST dataset into my code and it works 100% without any tweaks to the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my convnet and for me the reason was simply a combination of the following:

- not enough iterations: it can take quite a while for a change to become visible (tens of thousands of iterations)
- model to complicated: drastically reduce the number of filters for first tests and then slowly increase them to fit your use case to make sure it is not something else.

To get better debugging, try visualising your filters with Tensorboard, this gist helped me a lot:

https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5

Either of your approaches (`tf.layers` & manually created variables) should correctly connect to the `train_op`, so I do not think something is wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try running it with small parameters, but I suspect that it is not the case. Here's 1.8 epochs of data (100000 runs) passed to train_op and it has literally changed nothing.

[graph_from_tensorboard](https://ibb.co/bSt3X5)